# Documentum error : [DM_SESSION_E_RPC_ERROR]

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, documentum-dfs, documentum-dfc, documentum7.3

I am trying to get the content of all the documents (current version) from a documentum source using the following code

```
IDfSysObject document = (IDfSysObject) session.getObject(new DfId(eachFileMetadata.get(some document id).toString()));
ByteArrayInputStream docContent = document.getContent();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
       DfIOException:: THREAD: Thread-585; MSG: [DM_SESSION_E_RPC_ERROR]error:  "Server communication failure"; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfIOException.newCommunicationFailureException(DfIOException.java:16)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.netwise.AbstractNetwiseRpcClient.receiveMessage(AbstractNetwiseRpcClient.java:193)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.netwise.NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.getBlock(NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.java:1042)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.getBlock(DocbaseConnection.java:1475)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.RawPuller.getBlock(RawPuller.java:52)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.BlockPuller.nextBlock(BlockPuller.java:49)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.PullerInputStream.getNextBuffer(PullerInputStream.java:73)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.PullerInputStream.ensureBufferHasData(PullerInputStream.java:63)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.content.impl.PullerInputStream.read(PullerInputStream.java:88)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at com.documentum.fc.impl.util.io.StreamUtility.copyContents(StreamUtility.java:50)
    at com.documentum.fc.impl.util.io.StreamUtility.copyContents(StreamUtility.java:30)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContentEx3(DfSysObject.java:1952)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContentEx2(DfSysObject.java:1942)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfSysObject.getContent(DfSysObject.java:1932)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfDocument___PROXY.getContent(DfDocument___PROXY.java)
```

the above error occured when I am trying to get the content of a document,can anyone please help me??

Comment: try to check if content server/repository is up and fine first(check with your admins if you are not admin) or check in DA or any other Documentum client too, make sure it is up and fine.